# Symfony setting value of specific checkbox from db?

Tags: forms, symfony1, checkbox

I want to set checkbox to be checked for form rendered for specific value alone  which i have retrieved from database. I can do it in jQuery, but is there any specific library functions in Symfony?

Suggestions please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this....

on showing the form in first you can also pass the value in form while setting

```
 $this->samplevariable = YOURFORM($this->getYOURMODEL->setYOURFORMFIELDNAME(array of values(1,2,3) which u get form db getYOURFORMFIELDNAME);
```